# Reference correct this within callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript

I have a class function in Typescript that adds a circle to google maps and adds an event listener.  Within that listener I want to reference `this`, asign the object I am adding the listener too. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930145/94278) as a reference on how it would work in pure JS

Unfortunately Typescript stops me from referencing the correct this, how do I fix this *(problem, as opposed to this)*?

```
public drawGeoFence(/* params removed */) : void {
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, "mouseover", (event) => {
        this.showGeofenceInfoWindow(map, geofence, this); // <<- this!
    });
}
```

Comment: Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196) and [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a **`function`**, not an *arrow function*

```
public drawAThing(/* params removed */) : void {
    let self = this;
    //google.maps.event.addListener(circle, "mouseover", (event) => {
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, "mouseover", function(event){
        self.showGeofenceInfoWindow(map, geofence, this); // <<- this!
    });
}
```

Also, to have an access to original `showGeofenceInfoWindow` we need some more coding... to keep the original `this` in the `self` variable

Comment: Why can't you use this for the `showGeofenceInfoWindow`?

Comment: Because `this` now references the local function scope as opposed to the class

Comment: @Blubberguy22 this will be coming from different context. The *magic* which Typescript does with arrow functions,  won't be applied... Check this for detailed how to https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html