# Google maps InfoWindow popup flickering and onPointerEnter/onPointerLeave boundary issues

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have a popup that is made using InfoWindow from @react-google-maps/api. The behavior I am aiming for is to have place markers on the map that when hovered over, invokes a popup above the marker. If the mouse is over either the marker or the popup, the popup remains. If the mouse leaves either, then the popup disappears.

I have made something that is close to this behavior, however the popup flickers and the component the mouse can be on in the popup to not trigger the popup disappearing is smaller than the popup InfoWindow as it is confined to a div inside InfoWindow.

I think the main problem that InfoWindow blocks the marker when it appears, but since the onPointerEnter/onPointerLeave lies with the div inside InfoWindow, then the flicker starts as the mouse is first on the marker, then is on the InfoWindow above the marker but not on the div part. So the InfoWindow disappears and then the mouse is on the marker again, re-triggering onMouseOver for the place marker. Is there a way to either expand the div to be the exact same size of the InfoWindow, or use something like onPointerEnter or onPointerLeave for the InfoWindow itself?

EDIT: the below code is not sufficient, for a full example of the behavior see the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-star-qckhtl?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker, InfoWindow } from '@react-google-maps/api';


const MapComponent = ({ places }) => {
  const [isMapApiLoaded, setIsMapApiLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [selectedPlace, setSelectedPlace] = React.useState(null);
  const [isMouseOverInfoWindow, setIsMouseOverInfoWindow] = useState(false);
  const closeTimeoutRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <LoadScript
      googleMapsApiKey={MAP_KEY}
      onLoad={() => setIsMapApiLoaded(true)}
    >
      <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
        {isMapApiLoaded ? (
          <GoogleMap
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 37.77, lng: -122.51 }}
          >
            {/* Place markers */}
            {places.map((place, index) => (
              <Marker
                key={index}
                position={place.position}
                title={place.name}
                onMouseOver={() => {
                  if (closeTimeoutRef.current) {
                      clearTimeout(closeTimeoutRef.current);
                  }
                  setSelectedPlace(place);
                }}
                onMouseOut={() => {
                    closeTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
                      if (!isMouseOverInfoWindow) {
                        setSelectedPlace(null);
                      }
                    }, 300); // 300ms delay to move to the InfoWindow
                }}
              />
            ))}
            {/* Selected place marker */}
            {selectedPlace && (
              <InfoWindow
                position={selectedPlace.position}
                options={{ disableAutoPan: true }}
              >
                <div
                  onPointerEnter={() => {
                    setIsMouseOverInfoWindow(true);
                    if (closeTimeoutRef.current) {
                        clearTimeout(closeTimeoutRef.current);
                    }
                  }}
                  onPointerLeave={() => {
                    setIsMouseOverInfoWindow(false);
                    setSelectedPlace(null);
                  }}
                  style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    padding: '0',
                    margin: '0',
                    backgroundColor: "#23a681"
                  }}
                >
                  <h4>{selectedPlace.name}</h4>
                  <p>{selectedPlace.address}</p>
                </div>
              </InfoWindow>
            )}
          </GoogleMap>
        ) : (
          <div>Map API not loaded</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </LoadScript>
  );
}

export default MapComponent;
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue after trying out the code you provided, can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue? You can use codesandbox or any other snippet websites that allows react.

Comment: Sorry you're right my code example was faulty I have now attached a link to a codesandbox example

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, but I still do not see any marker nor info window in the code you provided in sandbox

Comment: Thats odd, I went to look and you're right, they are not appearing and I cannot figure out why. I noticed that when I mess with the keys for the places Marker (I comment them out and then comment them back in), the markers appear for some reason, but not on load

Comment: I managed to fix your code by using the `place.location.lat` as key for each marker. I'm currently taking a look at it.

Comment: Oh right, editing the key makes the markers show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your `InfoWindow` component should be enclosed within the `Marker` component to fix the flickering issue

I fixed the issue where the markers does not initially load by changing the component from `Marker` and `InfoWindow` to `MarkerF` and `InfoWindowF`.

This is because the ones with `F` suffixes are more compatible with functional Components like you are using.

With that said, the flickering was initially caused by your `InfoWindow` not properly anchored to the `Marker`. So what I did was enclose it like this:

Instead of this: `<MarkerF /><InfoWindowF />`

It should be like this: `<MarkerF><InfoWindowF /></MarkerF>`

So in your code, it should look something like this:

```
{/* Place markers */}
{places &&
places.map((place) => (
  <MarkerF
    key={place.key}
    position={place.position}
    title={place.name}
    // icon={getIconForPlace(place.type)}
    onMouseOver={() => {
      if (closeTimeoutRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(closeTimeoutRef.current);
      }
      setSelectedPlace(place);
    }}
    onMouseOut={() => {
      closeTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isMouseOverInfoWindow) {
          setSelectedPlace(null);
        }
      }, 300); // 300ms delay to move to the InfoWindow
    }}
  >
    {/* Selected place marker */}
    {selectedPlace && place.key === selectedPlace.key && (
      <InfoWindowF
        onMouseOver={() => {
          console.log("Mouse entered info window");
        }}
        position={place.position}
        options={{ disableAutoPan: true }}
      >
        <div
          className={`place-popup`}
          onPointerEnter={() => {
            setIsMouseOverInfoWindow(true);
            if (closeTimeoutRef.current) {
              clearTimeout(closeTimeoutRef.current);
            }
          }}
          onPointerLeave={() => {
            setIsMouseOverInfoWindow(false);
            setSelectedPlace(null);
          }}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            padding: "0",
            margin: "0",
            color: "#000000",
            backgroundColor: "#23a681"
          }}
        >
          <h2>{place.name}</h2>
          <div className="divider"></div>
          <div className="info-pair">{place.address}</div>
        </div>
      </InfoWindowF>
    )}
  </MarkerF>
))}
```

But because this change breaks your code, you need to make some more changes. So first thing you'll notice in the code I provided above is that I made some conditional statements to check if the current selected place has the same key with the info window we are trying to show. This is necessary because the `InfoWindow` component is now included with the `map` iteration of the `places` array.

This prevents the info window of both marker from showing together even if you only hover on a single marker.

Then for the information of your `InfoWindow` you should change how you are assigning the `position`, `name`, and `address` of it by changing `selectedPlaces.position`, `selectedPlaces.name`, and `selectedPlaces.address` to `place.position`, `place.position`, and `place.position`. Since you are still within the `map` iteration.

Though with regards to the `onpointerenter` and `onpointerleave` that only activates within the `div` but not within the `InfoWindow` itself, I could not find the fix. There was a similar question about it here in Stack Overflow before that does not seem to have a solution that would fit your use case: [google maps v3 marker info window on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920738/google-maps-v3-marker-info-window-on-mouseover)

But there's a new Advanced Marker currently in Maps JS API and if you want, it might be worth your time to check it out, since there's a somewhat similar sample of what you wanted in the official docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/html-markers

Though you might have to make it work on React. So you can check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kxYqoY2WwE

Now finally, here's a code snippet if you want to check what I did to your code yourself: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-ace-hr3rsj?file=/src/MapComponent.js:2371-2484

I hope this helps somehow!

Comment: Thanks so much! This was the solution to the problem. I didn't see a difference in using InfoWindowF/MarkerF and InfoWindow/Marker but the solution to address anchoring the component worked!

Comment: That's great to hear! Using the Components with F suffix is just to improve compatibility as that works well with Functional Components.